# How to find GC time being spent in an application (from within the application)

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, mbeans

We want to know the GC time being spent in an application.

It is easy to do so from outside the application but we want to know it from within the application.

And take some corrective action if the GC time per minute is too high.

Here is the code written till now.

```
private Long prevGcObservingTime = null; // field in the class
private Long prevGcDuration = null; // field in the class

boolean isGcTimeHigh(boolean printStats)
{
    List<GarbageCollectorMXBean> mxBeans = ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans();
    long totalGcSinceStartup = 0;
    for (GarbageCollectorMXBean mxBean: mxBeans)
    {
      if (mxBean instanceof com.sun.management.GarbageCollectorMXBean)
      {
        com.sun.management.GarbageCollectorMXBean internal = (com.sun.management.GarbageCollectorMXBean) mxBean;
        GcInfo gcInfo = internal.getLastGcInfo();
        totalGcSinceStartup += gcInfo.getDuration();
      }
    }
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (prevGcObservingTime == null)
    {
      // collecting GC for the first time
      prevGcObservingTime = currentTime;
      prevGcDuration = totalGcSinceStartup;
      return false;
    }
    double deltaDuration = (currentTime - prevGcObservingTime)/1000.0;
    if (deltaDuration <= 1)
    {
      // time between two measurements should be reasonable 
      return false;
    }
    if (deltaDuration > 60)
    {
      // too much time gap can have skewed measurement from a brief GC eruption
      prevGcObservingTime = currentTime;
      prevGcDuration = totalGcSinceStartup;
      return false;
    }
    double gcTimePerSecond = (totalGcSinceStartup - prevGcDuration)/deltaDuration;
    prevGcObservingTime = currentTime;
    prevGcDuration = totalGcSinceStartup;

    if (printStats)
      log.info("prevGcDuration={}, totalGcSinceStartup={}, deltaDuration={}, gcTimePerSecond={}",
        prevGcDuration, totalGcSinceStartup, deltaDuration, gcTimePerSecond);

    return false;
}
```

And here is the output:

```
2015-01-14 22:27:55.227; prevGcDuration=691, totalGcSinceStartup=691, deltaDuration=1.001, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:28:07.576; prevGcDuration=691, totalGcSinceStartup=691, deltaDuration=12.349, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:28:08.690; prevGcDuration=676, totalGcSinceStartup=676, deltaDuration=19.56, gcTimePerSecond=-0.7668711656441718
2015-01-14 22:28:08.854; prevGcDuration=675, totalGcSinceStartup=675, deltaDuration=13.245, gcTimePerSecond=-1.20800302000755
2015-01-14 22:28:22.210; prevGcDuration=670, totalGcSinceStartup=670, deltaDuration=14.634, gcTimePerSecond=-1.4350143501435013
2015-01-14 22:28:23.891; prevGcDuration=670, totalGcSinceStartup=670, deltaDuration=1.001, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:28:30.117; prevGcDuration=670, totalGcSinceStartup=670, deltaDuration=1.895, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:28:37.228; prevGcDuration=670, totalGcSinceStartup=670, deltaDuration=2.001, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:28:38.728; prevGcDuration=670, totalGcSinceStartup=670, deltaDuration=1.002, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:28:38.901; prevGcDuration=670, totalGcSinceStartup=670, deltaDuration=1.001, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:28:52.242; prevGcDuration=670, totalGcSinceStartup=670, deltaDuration=1.001, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:28:53.740; prevGcDuration=670, totalGcSinceStartup=670, deltaDuration=2.001, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:28:53.911; prevGcDuration=670, totalGcSinceStartup=670, deltaDuration=2.002, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:29:08.753; prevGcDuration=670, totalGcSinceStartup=670, deltaDuration=1.001, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:29:08.925; prevGcDuration=670, totalGcSinceStartup=670, deltaDuration=2.001, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:29:14.672; prevGcDuration=632, totalGcSinceStartup=632, deltaDuration=2.416, gcTimePerSecond=-15.728476821192054
2015-01-14 22:29:14.678; prevGcDuration=632, totalGcSinceStartup=632, deltaDuration=2.75, gcTimePerSecond=-13.818181818181818
2015-01-14 22:29:16.056; prevGcDuration=632, totalGcSinceStartup=632, deltaDuration=1.384, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:29:37.657; prevGcDuration=632, totalGcSinceStartup=632, deltaDuration=15.594, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:29:37.673; prevGcDuration=632, totalGcSinceStartup=632, deltaDuration=16.988, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:29:37.678; prevGcDuration=632, totalGcSinceStartup=632, deltaDuration=25.922, gcTimePerSecond=-1.46593627034951
2015-01-14 22:29:52.693; prevGcDuration=632, totalGcSinceStartup=632, deltaDuration=1.001, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:29:52.693; prevGcDuration=632, totalGcSinceStartup=632, deltaDuration=1.001, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:29:52.701; prevGcDuration=632, totalGcSinceStartup=632, deltaDuration=1.001, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:29:59.707; prevGcDuration=632, totalGcSinceStartup=632, deltaDuration=1.001, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:30:08.562; prevGcDuration=632, totalGcSinceStartup=632, deltaDuration=8.862, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:30:10.218; prevGcDuration=632, totalGcSinceStartup=632, deltaDuration=1.656, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:30:10.221; prevGcDuration=632, totalGcSinceStartup=632, deltaDuration=10.514, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:30:11.303; prevGcDuration=632, totalGcSinceStartup=632, deltaDuration=1.085, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:30:12.364; prevGcDuration=632, totalGcSinceStartup=632, deltaDuration=1.061, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:30:29.293; prevGcDuration=632, totalGcSinceStartup=632, deltaDuration=16.929, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:30:29.297; prevGcDuration=632, totalGcSinceStartup=632, deltaDuration=19.076, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
2015-01-14 22:30:30.838; prevGcDuration=632, totalGcSinceStartup=632, deltaDuration=1.545, gcTimePerSecond=0.0
```

Problem is that the **totalGcSinceStartup** seems to get stuck at some number after a while.

And it does not go away even if the application is run for hours.

Can someone point out the mistake here?

Comment: "And take some corrective action if the GC time per minute is too high"... this sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Edward, ours is a cloud with several nodes. If a node is doing very high GC pauses, we do not want it to eventually die. We want to just cool it off for some time so that it can resume operations soon. So this function can help us put that node into resting phase if its very high on GC (offcourse there are other params as well but this GC one is not working currently).

Comment: This is an extremely bad idea. If your application is experiencing problematic GC pauses under normal load conditions, then you need to solve the problem, not just shove it off onto another node to suffer for a while instead.

Answer (score 1):

I found a silly mistake:

```
    GcInfo gcInfo = internal.getLastGcInfo();
    totalGcSinceStartup += gcInfo.getDuration();
```

So the time returned cannot be total GC since startup.

Its just the sum of durations for the last occuring GCs.

Correct code is:

```
long totalGcSinceStartup = 0;
for (GarbageCollectorMXBean mxBean: mxBeans)
    totalGcSinceStartup += mxBean.getCollectionTime();
```